# Pandas calculated column from datetime index groups loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas df with a Datetime Index. I want to loop over the following code with different values of strike, based on the index date value (different strike for different time period). Here is my code that produces what I am after for 1 strike across the whole time series:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index=pd.date_range('2017-10-1 00:00:00', '2018-12-31 23:50:00', freq='30min')
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(index),2).cumsum(axis=0),columns=['A','B'],index=index)

strike = 40
payoffs = df[df>strike]-strike
mean_payoff = payoffs.fillna(0).mean()
dist = mean_payoff.describe(percentiles=[0.05,.5,.95])

print(dist)
```

I want to use different values of `strike` based on the time period (index value).

So far I have tried to create a categorical calculated column with the intention of using map or apply row wise on the df. I have also played around with creating a dictionary and mapping the dict across the df.
Even if I get the calculated column with the correct strike value, I can 't think how to subtract the calculated column value (strike) from all other columns to get `payoffs` from above.

I feel like I need to use for loop and potentially create groups of date chunks that get appended together at the end of the loop, maybe with pd.concat.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide a concrete example/test case for reproducible code

Comment: Does that help? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think you need convert `DatetimeIndex` to `quarter` period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), then to `string` and last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`.

For comapring need [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) with [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
d = {'2017Q4':30, '2018Q1':40, '2018Q2':50, '2018Q3':60, '2018Q4':70}
strike = df.index.to_series().dt.to_period('Q').astype(str).map(d)
payoffs = df[df.gt(strike, 0)].sub(strike, 0)

mean_payoff = payoffs.fillna(0).mean()
dist = mean_payoff.describe(percentiles=[0.05,.5,.95])
```

Comment: This is really helpful thanks! The only question I have is that my dates are in YYYY-DD-MM and the df.to_period('Q') thinks it is YYYY-MM-DD, is there a way to pass monthfirst=False or something similar? I tried pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(df.index.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))).dt.to_period('Q').astype(str).map(d) but ended up with this error: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'

Comment: Do you think your real data have format `YYYY-DD-MM`? Then need `(pd.to_datetime(df.index, format="%Y-%d-%m")).to_series().dt.to_period('Q').astype(str).map(d)`

Comment: And need to_series() not pd.Series, because need datetimeindex

Answer (score 0):

Mapping your dataframe index into a dictionary can be a starting point.

```
a = dict()
a[2017]=30
a[2018]=40
ranint = random.choices([30,35,40,45],k=21936)
#given your index used in example
df = pd.DataFrame({values:ranint},index=index)



                      values  year  strick
2017-10-01 00:00:00      30  2017      30
2017-10-01 00:30:00      30  2017      30
2017-10-01 01:00:00      45  2017      30

df.year = df.index.year
index.strike = df.year.map(a)
df.returns = df.values - df.strike
```

Then you can extract return that are greater than 0:

```
df[df.returns>0]
```